# How would you implement a BLoC to emit the statuses of all CRUD calls?

Tags: flutter, architecture, crud, bloc

I wonder about the best design and would like to invite your opinions.

Imagine a BLoC for Buildings. I want to implement CRUD calls to a API.

The simplest implementation would be (in pseudo code).

```
BuildingCubit {
  loadBuildings() {
    try {
      buildings = repository.loadBuildings()
      emit(BuildingsLoaded(buildings))
    } catch(error) {
      emit(BuildingsLoadError(error))
    }
  }
// example with add:
  addBuilding(building) {
    repository.addBuilding(building)
    loadBuildings()
  }
}
```

And now I would like to add a status to the `repository.addBuilding` call.

How would you do that? Would you implement a state with a child object that has entries like `addBuildingStatus` and perhaps `addBuildingError` that would be copied with an `copyWith` method? I don't want the bloc to emit a State like `BuildingsLoadError` when the add call fails, because I want to have the buildings list. Also I hesitate to implement a BLoC for each call.

I hope the question was clear enough, as it is more an architectural one than an syntax related one. But I can provide a full code example if it is needed for better understanding.

Thank you very much for your thoughts!